# Toggle between content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, bootstrap-5

I have the following Bootstrap version 4.1.1 page. I would like to change the background color of active toggle to white.

```css
.nav-tabs {
  margin-top: 3%;
  border: none;
  background: #0062cc;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  width: 28%;
  float: right;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link {
  padding: 2%;
  height: 34px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
  border: none;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  width: 100px;
  color: #d8dfe6;
  border: 2px solid #0062cc;
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<div class="col-md-9 register-right">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Buyer</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " id="profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Seller</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: .nav-tabs .nav-link:active { background: white; }
It activates briefly when I switch between, but doesn't maintain its active state.

Comment: You need Javascript to do that... to apply an "active" or "current" class.

Comment: When asking a question involving bootstrap, please specify  the correct bootstrap version in the tags. You have bootstrap 5 in your tags but  both bootstrap 3 and 4 in your JsFiddle.

Comment: Maintain active state _when_? Bootstrap tab styles already persist with the `active` class, which is applied by the library.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap handles the active states for you using the .active class. This is on the `nav-item`, not the `nav-link` however. The following should solve your problem.

```css
.nav-tabs {
  margin-top: 3%;
  border: none;
  background: #0062cc;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  width: 28%;
  float: right;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link {
  padding: 2%;
  height: 34px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
  border: none;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item.active .nav-link {
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #0062cc;
  color: #0062cc;
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.coam/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-9 register-right">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " id="home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Buyer</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " id="profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Seller</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your answers here what I found.

Here what i did.

create a class named tab in both list items and set one active.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " class="tab active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Buyer</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " class="tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Seller</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

use the following css to switch between

```
.active, .tab:hover 
    {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
    }
```

entire code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
<style>
    


.nav-tabs{
    margin-top: 3%;
    border: none;
    background: #0062cc;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-link{
    padding: 2%;
    height: 34px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover{
    border: none;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-link{
    width: 100px;
    color: rgb(240, 237, 237);
    border: 2px solid #0062cc;
    border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
.active, .tab:hover 
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
  
</style>              
<div class="col-md-9 register-right">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " class="tab active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Buyer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " class="tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Seller</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
                       
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.